# how to manage dynamic bootstrap carousel slides based on search filter in jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-carousel

I am facing challenges about how to manage dynamic bootstrap carousel slides.
the requirement is my filter functionality work on dropdown menu selection and also on checkbox check.

I have 5 div sections in a each slide. if div length goes 5+ it will show in next slide.

When I select dropdown menus option, for ex. I select option1 from dropdown list the all 'option1' related div should display in a slide, if the div size is less than 5 then only one slide will be display, and if div size is 5+ so next divs will display in another slide.
There is one more challenge is when you select 'option1' and then click on checkboxes that divs also re-filter.

I tried with array and loop but didn't get any solution. please help.

My Structure looks like this:

```
<div class="FilterSection">
        <select class="category form-control" >
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <div class="checkboxSection" style="color:red;">
        <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox1" /> Checkbox1 
        <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox2" /> Checkbox2 
        <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox3" /> Checkbox3 
        <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox4" /> Checkbox4 
        <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox5" /> Checkbox5 
    </div>
    <div class="filterResultSection">
        <div class="option1 checkbox1 well text-info">Div container 1</div>
        <div class="option2 checkbox2 well text-info">Div container 2</div>
        <div class="option3 checkbox3 well text-info">Div container 3</div>
        <div class="option4 checkbox4 well text-info">Div container 4</div>
        <div class="option2 checkbox5 well text-info">Div container 5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the whole code. Styles, HTML, JS and eternal plugins. if possible put them in a JS Fiddle. Thanks.

Comment: @Tanvi : https://jsfiddle.net/poojaparge/7dcrz22u/4/

I have created actual example please check. also on load I have slice and wrap div in .item, but in filter process the item container should be updated with new records and override existing slide